Do we use "land on one's feet" when we make an effort to get out of a bad situation or we get out of it by luck?
Cambridge dictionary says

land on your feet idiom
to be in good condition after a difficult experience:
She lost her job last year, but she landed on her feet and found
another one a week later.

Oxford dictionary says
fall/land on your feet

​to be lucky in finding yourself in a good situation, or in getting
out of a difficult situation
You landed on your feet, getting such a well-paid job with so little
experience.
Jim’s always getting himself in trouble, but he usually seems to fall
on his feet.

It seems like "land on one's feet" has some luck involved.
Say, I have applied for hundreds of jobs but couldn't get one. Then, I get my act together, get more certificates, improve English skills, practice for interviews. And, 1 year later, I got a job.
Is it correct to say "I've finally landed on my feet with a new job" in that situation?

It's not an either-or situation. You can land on your feet by luck, or land on you feet by shrewd response to adverse circumstances. "
So, to "land on your feet" is to emerge OK from difficult circumstances, however that occurs.

... though maybe "fall on one's feet" implies a greater element of luck.

You said "land on you feet by shrewd response".
are  "he got on his feet with a new job" and "he landed on his feet with a new job" the same?

@Tom  The usual phrase is "He got back on his feet."   It implies that a person has come back from some kind of misfortune or personal problem that turned their life upside down, such as a long period of unemployment resulting in homelessness, or an addiction.  A person of whom that phrase is used did not land on their feet first time around.  A person who lands on their feet manages to avoid a bad outcome, to emerge from the bad circumstances relatively unscathed. The dire outcome is averted.
